# Homepage spammed

Tags: bug

Today, the home page was spammed with edits by "alip" apparently but "alip" never seems to have made said edits. Regardless it bumped a ton of questions and now the home page is quite crowded.
First, is this a bug?
Second, did "Alip" actually make these edits?
Third, are these types of mass-editing unanswered questions allowed?
Fourth, (if applicable) what can be done to prevent this?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

alip did actually write a lot of answers, they've just all been deleted (they're there, but you need a certain amount of rep to see deleted answers). I wonder why. At a guess, it'd be because alip appears to be an AI, e.g. their answer to [Are engines impaired by the 50-move rule?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/39749/are-engines-impaired-by-the-50-move-rule) starts with "The 50-move rule in chess states that a player can claim a draw if no capture has been made and no pawn has been moved in the last 50 moves. It's a rule designed to prevent endless games and to discourage players from persisting in a position with no realistic hope of progress" -- which is completely irrelevant.

Comment: The answers all follow a similar structure and wordy style used by AIs which made me suspect AI was involved. But some of the info of the answers appear to be useful.