# Homepage Spammed - Again

Tags: discussion

Today, the home page was spammed ([again](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1195/26335)) with edits or answers by "user 34927". It bumped a ton of questions and now the home page is quite crowded.
First, what happened?
Second, this is the second time I have seen this, so what can be done to prevent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> First, what happened?

Asked and answered.

> Second, this is the second time I have seen this, so what can be done
> to prevent this?

TL;DR:  **Vote and/or flag appropriately.**

Nothing changes.  As always...

- Vote on the posts.<sup>[1,2]</sup>
- Vote to close<sup>[3]</sup> as appropriate if you have the rep.
- Flag for moderator attention when appropriate and provide specific details why you are flagging. In the words of Jeff Atwood (co-founder), "*when you see something bad happening on the site — flag it!*"<sup>[4]</sup>

<sub>References:

<sub>1. [Vote Early. Vote Often](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30/26335)</sub>

<sub>2. [Why is voting important?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)</sub>

<sub>3. https://chess.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions</sub>

4. [Improved Flagging](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/14/improved-flagging)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

> First, what happened?

You described what happened in your question. Fortunately your moderators were not on strike and the offending AI generated answers were deleted.

> Second, this is the second time I have seen this, so what can be done to prevent this?

Your hard working, unpaid moderators can not go on strike and need to be vigilant to try and handle these incidents promptly.

By the way, good to see that you are no longer on strike.

Comment: I am still on strike, I didn't flag any of these. Once they were deleted, and only then, did I say something. And this seem like a rant against strikers.